# I need to know what happening behind the screen while executing the following code

Tags: c#

### Class---A

```
class ClassA
{
    public string c1()
    {
        return "Class-A";
    }

}
```

### Class---B

```
class ClassB:ClassA
{
    public string c2()
    {
        return "Class-B";
    }
}
```

### Main Class

-----Part 1------------------

```
 ClassA obj1 = new ClassB();
 string a = obj1.c1();//Here i will get only c1
 Console.WriteLine(a);
 Console.ReadLine();
```

-----Part 2------------------

```
 ClassB obj1 = new ClassA();
 string a = obj1.c2();//Her i will get both c1 and c2
 Console.WriteLine(a);
 Console.ReadLine();
```

**In Part-1**,i will get only c1.I need to know whether variable (obj) is created for ClassA in **stack** and assign address of ClassB from **Heap**.What is actually happening?

**In Part -2** ,Getting(compilation error) conversion error.What is actually happening behind the screen while executing this code.

Thanks,
Joby Kurian

Comment: The `Class---A` and `Class---B` you have shown in your question look utterly the same. Wrong copy-paste?

Comment: Now your `-----Part 2------------------` doesn't even compile. You cannot write `ClassB obj1 = new ClassA()`. Please take some more time when preparing your question.

Comment: Your part 2 example won't compile.  ClassB extends ClassA, not the other way around.

Comment: Re: Part 2 - ClassB inherits from ClassA, so `ClassB obj1 = new ClassA()` is an error (ClassA is not convertible to a ClassB reference).      Also, as for stack-vs-heap, any objects created using the the **new** keyword will end up on the heap

Comment: Yep, he does **say** he gets a compilation error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...Yes...Part-2 won't compile.Part 1-What is happeing in memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Part 1**

```
ClassA obj1 = new ClassB();
```

This creates an *instance* of `ClassB` - an object.

It also declares a *variable* called `obj1`, of type `ClassA`. That variable's *value* will always be a reference - either `null` or a reference to an instance of `ClassA`. In this case, the initial value is a reference to the newly created `ClassB` object. (A reference to a `ClassB` object can be used as a `ClassA` reference too, because `ClassB` derives from `ClassA`.)

When you call `c1`, it just calls the implementation in `ClassA` - but within that method, if you printed out `this.GetType()` it would still return `ClassB`'s type, as it's operating "within" a `ClassB` object.

I strongly suggest you *don't* worry about the stack and the heap yet. Focus on the three different *concepts*:

- Objects
- References (ways of navigating to objects, or null)
- Variables (named storage locations)

Eric Lippert has blogged a *lot* about this sort of thing. You might want to start with [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx).

**Part 2**

```
ClassB obj1 = new ClassA();
```

This creates an instance of `ClassA`, and tries to assign a reference to the new object to a variable of type `ClassB`. That doesn't work, because `ClassA` does *not* derive from `ClassB`. You can't use a reference of compile-time type `ClassA` to a variable of type `ClassB`. As a demonstration of *why* this wouldn't work, it's a bit like doing this:

```
string x = new object();
Console.WriteLine(x.Length); // What could this possibly print out?
```

Basically, inheritance doesn't work that way round - you can treat an instance of `ClassB` as an instance of `ClassA` (in most cases) but you *can't* treat an instance of `ClassA` as an instance of `ClassB`. You'd normally be adding more state (fields) in `ClassB`, so that information just wouldn't be present in the instance of `ClassA`.

Comment: -Thank for your reply...Can you explain little more about this words:-"A reference to a ClassB object can be used as a ClassA reference too, because ClassB derives from ClassA."I really want to know the background?Plz...

Comment: @JobyKurian: That's part of the purpose of inheritance - to be able to use an instance of a derived type as an instance of a base type. I'm not sure what more there is to say about it that's suitable for comments rather than an introductory book on C#.

Answer (score 0):

What happens (in part II) is that you are trying to instanciate class A as a variable of class B. This cannot be done, because the variable must have the available properties accessible in the instanciated object. So when you try call the method c2() it is non-existant in the object. The other way round works fine, because all the available properties and methods of the variable exists in the instanciated object.

Answer (score 0):

you are making an object of class A and calling class B's constructor make an object of that particular class mate.and then access the properties. Why are you amking things intriguing for you!